# Get higher value when searching in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I have code which finds the closest number in the array with given value.

In the following example the output will be `5` because it's the closest available number. However I want the output to be `15` because the customer wants `7` so he has to buy the `15` option.

When the customer enters `60` it should revert back to `55` because that is the last option.

How can I fix this?

```js
var array = ["5", "15", "30", "55"];
var input = 7;
let output = closest(array, input);
console.log(output);

function closest(arr, closestTo) {
  var result,
    lastDelta;

  arr.some(function(item) {
    var delta = Math.abs(closestTo - item);
    if (delta > lastDelta) {
      return true;
    }
    result = item;
    lastDelta = delta;
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the array to convert the string values to integers? Are the values guaranteed to be in ascending order?

Comment: I also fixed the variable name in your example; you'd redefined `closest`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find` instead - just find the first item whose value is higher than or equal to the `closest` parameter:

```js
var array = ["5", "15", "30", "55"];

const closest = (arr, numToFind) => arr.find(x => x >= numToFind) || arr[arr.length - 1];

console.log(closest(array, 7));
```

If the array might not be sorted first, either sort it ahead of time, or (less complex) iterate through it more imperatively, checking the values:

```js
var array = ["5", "15", "30", "55"];

const closest = (arr, numToFind) => {
  const largest = Math.max(...arr);
  let bestSoFar = Infinity;
  for (const num of arr) {
    if (num >= numToFind && num < bestSoFar) {
      bestSoFar = num;
    }
  }
  return bestSoFar ?? largest;
};

console.log(closest(array, 7));
```

Comment: How is this solution valid for an array which is not sorted?

Comment: It appears that the array may already be sorted, from the code in the question. If it's not, it's easy to sort it first

Comment: Yes was just pointing out that the array needs to be sorted first since the question doesn't mention anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

This will take care of searching for the next largest number and revert back to the max available, It is a modified version of CertainPerformance's response.

```js
const
  array = [ "5", "15", "30", "55" ],
  closest = (arr, n) => arr.find(x => x >= n) || arr[arr.length - 1];

console.log(closest(array, 3));  // 5
console.log(closest(array, 7));  // 15
console.log(closest(array, 60)); // 55
```